# How to handle document.registerElement deprecation in Polymer v1?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, custom-element

In the browser console, I see:

> [Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated and will be
>   removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use
>   window.customElements.define instead. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more
>   details.

It's coming from `polymer-micro.html:443`, which is coming from my Polymer 1.11.3 package in my project. I believe that's the latest v1 version.

How do I handle this without updating Polymer to v2? I tried updating to Polymer 2, but it's failing at runtime. I guess the api changed.

Comment: Are you using the webcomponents v0 polyfills? I think that should do it

Comment: @AlanDávalos that is actually the answer. Put it so I can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For polymer v1 based components to work with the latest versions of modern browsers you should add the Web Components v0 polyfills in a way similar to this in your main html

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite-min.js"></script>
```

For more info on this check the polymer team's [blog post](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-10-02-webcomponents-v0-deprecations)